# Why does mkdir messes up special characters (german umlauts)?

Tags: locale, mkdir

I have a system which is set up with Debian. Running the command

```
mkdir xx_ü
```

on this system, creates a directory called `'xx_'$'\303\274'`. Running the same command on a system that is set up with Ubuntu creates a directory called `xx_ü` which is what I would need.

How do I get the system set up with Debian to create the directory correctly containing the german umlauts?

---

- Debian system: `Linux helios64 5.10.63-rockchip64 #21.08.2 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 8 10:57:23 UTC 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux`
- Ubuntu system: `Linux tikey-TUXEDO 5.13.0-28-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 13 17:41:06 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: The name is right, just your display locales wrong. Recent versions of GNU ls output  names it considers "unprintable" like that, using the shell's quoting syntax.

Comment: And keep in mind that for Linux, the filename is just a meaningless bytestring. It doesn't care if it's encoded in UTF-8 or latin-1, and if you move the disk to another Linux system with a different locale and different encoding, it will happily display garbage again.

Comment: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/configure-system-locale-on-debian-9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem was just the display of the folders which was messed up due to badly configured locales.

Running `locale` on the debian system would show (note the warning here):

```
~> locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_AT.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

but `locale -a` only showed

```
~> locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Note that `de_AT.UTF-8` is missing in the second list.

Running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and selecting `de_AT.UTF-8` solves the issue.